# Magento EE 1.14.1 catalog_product_flat table re-indexing issues

Tags: catalog, reindex, flat-catalog, enterprise-1.14, flat-indexer

We've recently discovered (after an upgrade) that `Magento EE 1.14.1` no longer keeps the `catalog_product_flat` tables updated unless you have `Use Flat Catalog Product` in `System->Config->Catalog->Frontend` enabled.

Even manually re-indexing through the shell does not populate `catalog_product_flat_1` like it used to in previous versions. I believe this change was made sometime on or after 1.13.

All previous versions would keep catalog_`product_flat_1` up to date regardless of this `Use Flat Catalog Product` setting.

We do not wish to enable `Use Flat Catalog Product` on the front-end, but somehow we need to keep `catalog_product_flat_1` updated as we have various extensions and feeds that use this table.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: the best option will be to contact your account manager and take his/her advice

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to update the flat data table.

```
   <?php

    define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    foreach($collection as $product){
        try{
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_flat_indexer')->updateProduct($product->getId(), null);
            echo "Successfully reindex product with id ". $product->getId();
        }
        catch(exception $ex){
            print_r($ex);
        }
    }
```

you can set the code in the php file and run that file as a cron job.